# Powershell Taking multiple args from lines in a text file and determining how many args to feed another script

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

Working on a PS script that takes all the trusts that a domain has and produces a text file with these domains (docs.example.com) and then splits by period.

AllADTrustsFormatted.txt 
this file contains

```
`   aaa.domain.org 
    bbb.subdomain.differentdomain.org
    ccc.some.other.domain.org
    ddd.domain
    BareWinDomain`
```

The master script needs to have 1-7 input parameters
(domain length with . as field separator)

This works great now all I need to do is figure out how to determine the fields to provide another master script that will run AD calls (Get-ADComputer) against the domain to output the servers that will need to be monitored. The master script that gets all the servers currently has to be run manually.

```
(e.g.  MasterScript.ps1 -DOMAIN aaa -DC1 aaa -DC2 aaa -DC3 bbb -DC4 org )
```

I'd like to get the AD Trusts then iterate through the file of domains (in and find all the systems with Server as a property. I'd like the master domain listing to be read in by the master script and it to dynamically figure out how many arguments (i.e. parts of the domain in the FQDN) and format the master script with the proper number data for the FQDN (see above).

This has to be an easier way than how I'm approaching this. I wanted to avoid running a function to figure the number of domain arguments and put them into files to be read through (e.g. 1Arg.txt 2Arg.txt 3Arg.txt )

As always many thanks in advance,

//\

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the master script, you should create a variable with your parameters, something like this:

```
$params = @{}
gc AllADTrustsFormatted.txt |% {
   $parts = $_ -split "\."
   $params.DOMAIN = $parts[0]
   1..($parts.Count - 1)|% {
      $params."DC$_" = $parts[$_] 
   }
}
& MasterScript.ps1 @params
```

Sorry if that was not what you wanted, it was difficult to figure out what the script should really pass to the master script...

Comment: This looks exactly what is needed! Thanks Hellon, you Rock! Trying now.

Comment: I just made one mistake, this code "$params = @{}" should be the first command